# Type switch to validate function by interface

Tags: go

I want to test a given function in runtime, to verify that it matches a certain signature. It's sufficient that this signature complies with some interface, not a specific implementation.

I can't seem to find the right pattern to do such validation. In runtime, the function's type is using the implementation.

How can I compare the function's signature to the interface?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myinteface interface{
    DoSomething(int) string
}

type myfunc func(myinteface)

type impl struct {}

func (im *impl) DoSomething(int) string{
    return "fsdfsd"
}

func do(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case func(myinteface):  
        fmt.Print("doesn't stop here")
    case func(impl):    
        fmt.Print("this does work")
    default:
        fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
    }
}

func test(im impl) {}

func main() {
    do(test)
}
```

see it live in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q578dXUR8Z)

Comment: What it's telling you is completely correct. `test` is a `func(impl)` and not a `func(myinteface)` and can't be used as a `func(myinteface)`.

Comment: I know it's correct... but `impl` does satisfy `myinterface`, so I want to know if I can tell that a function has an implementation of that interface in its signature

Comment: What @hobbs said, and addition: function types are *invariant* in Golang (as well as arrays and slices). Searching by that term would lead to a lot of various relevant articles.

Comment: Obviously I can't do what I was trying to do. Evidently it doesn't work. What I'm asking is if there is way to do this check in some other way

Comment: I think you can take a reflection and implement a type checker that could introduce covariance in this particular case, but it sounds complicated and error-prone. It would be better to reconsider the original design that does not require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check arguments type manually using [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package. Here's an example for `myinteface`. I check whether first parameter `Implements` desired interface. For brevity I suppose function has only one obligatory argument. For production it's better to check number of arguments (commented out string with `NumIn()`) and all their types in a cycle.

```
func do(i interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    typ := val.Type()
    // numIn := typ.NumIn()
    arg0 := typ.In(0)
    modelType := reflect.TypeOf((*myinteface)(nil)).Elem()
    if arg0.Implements(modelType) {
        fmt.Println("OK")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not OK")
    }
}
```

Also, please pay attention to a receiver type: value or pointer. For example, here only `test2` function argument implements `myinteface`, but `test` doesn't because of the pointer receiver on the struct `impl`.

```
func test(im impl) {}

func test2(im *impl) {}

func main() {
    do(test)
    do(test2)
}
```

Demo: https://play.golang.org/p/ZDZKZIh2lW

If you change struct definition to value receiver then both function's arguments implement it:

```
type impl struct{}

func (im impl) DoSomething(int) string {
    return "fsdfsd"
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xvasgBs-_a

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is a little hard to tell what you want to assert about the function. I wrote up something that I think does what you need.

Note that the function `test` in your question did not take a parameter that implements `myinteface` as it was not a pointer.

As mentoined, you probably need to find a different solution to your problem you are trying to solve using this.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type myinteface interface {
    DoSomething(int) string
}

type myfunc func(myinteface)

type impl struct{}

func (im *impl) DoSomething(int) string {
    return "fsdfsd"
}

//Does the function passed as `i` take a type that implements the `myinteface` type as first parameter
func do(i interface{}) {
    functionType := reflect.TypeOf(i)
    if functionType.Kind() != reflect.Func {
        fmt.Printf("(%s) is not a function", functionType)
    }
    ourInterfaceType := reflect.TypeOf((*myinteface)(nil)).Elem()
    if functionType.In(0).Implements(ourInterfaceType) {
        fmt.Printf("(%s)'s first paramter implements the `myinteface` interface\n", functionType)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("(%s)'s first paramter does not implement the `myinteface` interface\n", functionType)
    }
}

func test(im *impl) {}
func test2(im impl) {}

func main() {
    do(test)
    do(test2)
}
```